# SLF4JBridgeHandler не работает через logging.properties

Tags: java, jersey, slf4j

У меня есть проект, который использует:

- Apache Maven 3.3.3
- Project Jersey 1.17
- Spring 3.3.1
- Tomcat 6
- Eclipse IDE

Мне понадобилось писать в лог внутренную работу Jersey (HTTP запросы и ответы). Чтобы сделать это, добавил `LoggingFilter` в мой `web.xml`:

```
<init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
     <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
     <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
 </init-param>
```

Запустив проект в Eclipse я вижу что Jersey выводит логи в консоль Eclipse.

Теперь, Я хочу использовать `Logback` чтобы писать логи в файлы и использовать appender из другой библиотеки. Итак, я добавил в `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Чтобы перенаправиль все логи JUL (Jersey использует их внутри) через SLF4J API, я использую `org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler`

SLF4JBridgeHandler нужно инициализировать и попробовал сделать это создав
`src/main/resources/logging.properties` со следующим содержимым:

```
handlers = org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
```

как описано [тут](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html) и ничего не произошло.

Если использовать другой подход (Programmatic installation), то все работает как надо.

Почему не сработало с конфигурацией `logging.properties`? Что я упустил?

Comment: Вроде бы надо [явно указать конфиг](http://yatel.kramolis.cz/2013/11/how-to-configure-jdk-logging-for-jersey.html) для java.util.logging.

Comment: Разве недостаточно чтобы logging.properties находился в WEB-INF/classes в собранном war файле?